# Android Gradle Group Common Properties

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

Is there a way to group gradle properties to be reused? I can accomplish the following by having duplicate properties but I am trying to avoid this by grouping them in a common place. I have the following build types

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".qa" //Duplicate
    }
    qa2 {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".qa" //Duplicate
    }
    release {} 
}

flavors { 
    flagship {}
    other1 {}
    other2 {}
}
```

I already have different flavors defined so I don't think I can place the common properties in different flavors. I was hoping I'd be able to do something like

```
def commonQaProps {
   applicationIdSuffix = ".qa"
   //Other properties
}
```

and then have

```
qa { commonQaProps }
qa2 { commonQaProps }
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation if you're building one `buildType` off of another you can use `initWith`.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    qa {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".qa" //Duplicate
    }
    qa2 {
        initWith qa
        //Customize other properties here
    }
    release {} 
}
```

I still would like to know if grouping properties is possible to use in many variants that don't inherit from each other.